# Help with my PHP template class

Tags: php, class, templates

I want to separate the output of HTML from my program code in my projects, so I wrote a very simple database class.

```
<?php
class Template
{
    private $template;

    function load($filePath)
    {
        if(!$this->template = file_get_contents($filePath))
            $this->error('Error: Failed to open <strong>' . $filePath . '</strong>');
    }

    function replace($var, $content)
    {
        $this->template = str_replace("{$var}", $content, $this->template);
    }

    function display()
    {
        echo $this->template;
    }

    function error($errorMessage)
    {
        die('die() by template class: <strong>' . $errorMessage . '</strong>');
    }
}
?>
```

The thing I need help with is the `display()` method. Say for example I use this code:

```
$tplObj = new Template();
$tplObj->load('index.php');
$tplObj->replace('{TITLE}', 'Homepage');
$tplObj->display();
```

And the `index.php` file is this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{TITLE}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{TITLE}</h1>
        <?php
            if($something) {
                echo '$something is true';
            } else {
                echo '$something is false';
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm just wondering if the PHP code in there would be run? Or would it just be sent to the browser as plaintext? I was using `eval()` in my template class but I hate that function :P

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just try running it?

Comment: I also wanted to gather suggestions about what I should use to get PHP in a included file to run.

Answer (score 1):

No. It would come out plain text.

'echo' outputs without parsing PHP code.

You don't need to fall back on using eval. There are other ways for example using output buffering.